# Let $\theta : D \to \Bbb R^2, \theta(t,(x,y))=\theta_t(x,y)=(xe^{2t},ye^{-3t}).$ I need to find its infinitesmal generator. What is that?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $\mathcal{D}= \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^2$ and $\theta : \mathcal{D} \to \Bbb R^2$, $$\theta(t,(x,y))=\theta_t(x,y)=(xe^{2t},ye^{-3t}).$$ Show that $\theta$ is a flow and find its infinitesimal generator.

In Lee's intro to smooth manifolds he states that $\theta$ is a global flow if $$\theta(t, \theta(s,p))= \theta(t+s,p) \text{ and } \theta(0,p)=p.$$

So for $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$ we have that $\theta(t,\theta(s,(x,y))) = \theta(t, (xe^{2s},ye^{-3s}))=(xe^{2(s+t)}, ye^{-3(s+t)})= \theta(t+s,(x,y))$.

Also $\theta(0,(x,y))=(x,y)$ so this is indeed a flow.

The second part is something I don't understand. Lee talks about these infinitesimal generators as being some kind of "slides" along the integral curve for time $t$, but I don't quite understand what he means.

Also I cannot find a solid definition of what is meant by infinitesimal generator?

Comment: The infinitesimal generator is an object that describes local infinitesimal changes for the flow. In the present context, the generator is defined as $A(x,y) = \lim_{t\downarrow 0}\dfrac{\theta_t(x,y)-(x,y)}{t}$.

Comment: So the infinitesimal generator is $A(x,y)= y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Comment: No. I am not sure how you managed to get that. The generator in this case should map $\mathbb{R}^2$ to  $\mathbb{R}^2$. You just need to apply the formula I gave.

Comment: Is your question: "What is a solid definition of what is meant by infinitesimal generator?"  There is only one part here on which you're stuck, and I take it you mean to ask the quoted question.